# If any satisfiable $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})$-theory remains satisfiable when replacing $Q_{=κ}$ with $Q_{=μ}$, is $κ$ huge?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, large-cardinals

*Recently, I have asked a model-theoretic question concerning a weakening of different forms of compactness. I now present another model-theoretic question as a weakening of hugeness.*

---

**If any satisfiable $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})$-theory remains satisfiable when replacing $Q_{=κ}$ with $Q_{=μ}$, is $κ$ huge with target $μ$?**

Just for background, $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})$ is the infinitary logic which extends $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}$ by allowing the extra quantifier $Q_{=κ}$ meant to be read as "there are exactly $κ$-many...". The same is true with $Q_{=μ}$.

---

For motivation for this question, I'll first show that if $κ$ is huge with target $μ$ then any satisfiable $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})$-theory remains satisfiable when replacing $Q_{=κ}$ with $Q_{=μ}$.

**Proof:** Let $\kappa$ be huge as witnessed by the embedding $j:V\prec M$. Let $T$ be a satisfiable $\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})$-theory of vocabulary (language) $\tau$. Then, let $\mathcal{N}\models T$.

Consider $j(\mathcal{N})$. $j(\mathcal{N})$ is a $j(\tau)$-structure. Note that $j"\tau\subset j(\tau)$ and then take the $j"\tau$-reduct of $j(\mathcal{N})$ called $\mathcal{K}=j(\mathcal{N})\upharpoonright j"\tau$.

Interpret each $\varphi\in T$ as a $\kappa$-sequence of ordinals, each of which are elements of $\kappa$ or symbols of $\tau$ except for $Q_{=κ}$ which is interpreted as $\kappa$. Define $\models_{\mathcal{L}_{κ,κ}(Q_{=κ})}$ in the obvious way from these formulaic definitions. Then, $j(\varphi)=j\circ\varphi$ and since for each index $x$ of $\varphi$, $x$ is either $\kappa$ (in which case $j(\kappa)=\mu$), a symbol $s$ (in which case $j(s)\in j"\tau$), or an $\alpha\in\kappa$ (in which case $j(\alpha)=\alpha$), you have that **$j(\varphi)$ is the result of replacing each symbol $s$ with $j(s)$ and replacing $\kappa$ with $\mu$. Therefore $j(\varphi)^\rho=\psi$ where $\rho(j(s))=s$ and $\psi$ is $\varphi$ after replacing each instance of $Q_{=\kappa}$ with $Q_{=\mu}$.**

For each $\varphi\in T$, $\mathcal{N}\models\varphi$ and so $j(\mathcal{N})\models^M j(\varphi)$. Since $M^{\mu}\subset M$, $M$ is correct about the satisfaction relation for $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}(Q_{=\mu})$-theories and therefore $j(\mathcal{N})\models^M j(\varphi)$. As shown before, $j(\varphi)$ is a $j"\tau$-formula and therefore $\mathcal{K}=j(\mathcal{N})\upharpoonright j"\tau\models j(\varphi)$. Since $\mathcal{K}\models j(\varphi)$, $\mathcal{K}^\rho\models j(\varphi)^\rho$ where $\rho$ is the renaming described before. Therefore $\mathcal{K}^\rho\models\psi$ where $\psi$ is $\varphi$ except every instance of $Q_{=\kappa}$ is replaced with $Q_{=\mu}$. **As a result, $T$ remains satisfiable (via $\mathcal{K}^\rho$) after replacing $Q_{=\kappa}$ with $Q_{=\mu}$.**

---

### Motivation For this Question

It turns out that requiring that $M$ is correct about the satisfaction relation for $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}(Q_{=\mu})$ is equivalent to a slightly weaker (possibly weaker) form of huge-ness in which some subsets of $M$ of size $j(\kappa)$ may not necessarily be in $M$. This property is a generalization of the previous result about a weakening of strong compactness (which turned out to be equivalent to measurability), which has a similar proof due to the fact that $M$ is correct about $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}$.

It seems that using generalizations of this proof can only get you about to hugeness (generalizations of this proof can get you to extendibility) by doing proofs based on certain correctness conditions on $M$ about satisfaction relations of different logics. Perhaps huge-ness can be obtained through this method?

---

### Questions

The problem is, even though it is quite difficult to show that if $\kappa$ is huge with target $\mu$ then this strange phenomenon occurs, it is incredibly difficult to show that any interesting results come from this phenomenon. As a result, I'm going to ask for a little help on where I should go next:

1. Is this property equivalent to being huge?
2. Is this property too loose? That is, is there some property that huge-ness implies which strengthens this and is equivalent to huge-ness?
3. Is this property equivalent to any interesting large cardinal axioms if 2. fails?

---

### EDIT

As shown in the comments, there is a simple proof that this follows from $((j(\kappa))^+)^M=j(\kappa)^+$ (that $M$ computes the successor of $j(\kappa)$ correctly) which is quite weaker in consistency strength.

However, that still leaves open how one could get closer to the consistency strength of a huge cardinal. By requiring certain specifications of $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}^{II}$ one can get to extendibility (by treating extendibility as $2$-fold strongness).

It seems natural that the only part of this proof which could be strengthened is which logic is being used, as that changes the requirement about correctness. It is well known that $M$ is correct about $\mathcal{L}_{\mu,\mu}$ assuming $M^{<\mu}\subset M$, however it seems difficult to use that in a similar proof.

Comment: Are there any hypotheses on what $\mu$ is, or is it just some arbitrary cardinal $\not=\kappa$ *(OK fine, necessarily $\mu>\kappa$)*?

Comment: Looks like your argument only needs a $j : V\to M$ such that $\text{crt}(j) = \kappa$ and $|A|^M = j(\kappa)$ if and only if $|A| =j(\kappa)$. From Yair's answer to your last question it suffices that $j(\kappa)$ is a cardinal and $M$ correctly computes its successor. For this it is enough that $P(j(\kappa))$ is contained in $M$. But this is much weaker than a huge. It's weaker than $2$-extendible, I'm pretty sure, and certainly much weaker than supercompact.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg That's what it seems, although you may be forgetting that "$Q_{=\mu}$" questions whether or not there is a *subset* of the structure of size $\mu$ which satisfies the following formula. For example, there may not be a set $X\subset A$ where $X\in M$ and $|X|=\mu$ with $X$ satisfying the following formula, even though there would be in $V$.

Comment: In fact, I had the exact same argument as you (which was indeed why I asked the previous question in the first place). However, I realized that it may not be enough to require that.

Comment: Suppose $M$ is an inner model that is correct about which sets have cardinality $\mu$. Suppose $\mathcal N,\varphi\in M$ and for $x\in \mathcal N$, $M$ correctly computes whether $\mathcal N \vDash \varphi(x)$. Then $M$ is correct about whether $\mathcal N \vDash Q_{=\mu}x\ \varphi(x)$ since $|\{x\in \mathcal N : \mathcal N\vDash \varphi(x)\}| =\mu$ is absolute between $V$ and $M$. $M$ doesn't have to search for a set of size $\mu$, the set is defined by $\varphi$, no?

Comment: Oh yes, this is true. Perhaps there is a strengthening which can more closely approximate huge-ness?